# how to set a file in a fileInput in an HTML form

Tags: java, javascript, html, forms

I have a java form like

```
<form 
      action="/something.do" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      name="someForm" 
      method="post" 
      id="someFormID" 
      class="form1" 
      style="margin: 0px; clear: both; width: 730px;">

<input type="file" name="file"/>

</form>
```

now in the same JSP i need to set this file attribute a have a file ,but not by browsing but by simply adding the path or something like this.

I need to make this automated

any ways to achieve this ??

Comment: "i need to set this file attribute a have a file ,but not by browsing but by simply adding the path or something like this" . Not at all clear!

Comment: I don't think you can - nor would I want you to be able to do that. It would be a security hole that allows you to automagically download arbitrary files on the user's file system. The user HAS to be involved in the process. And PS: its a HTML form, not a Java form. Where it submits to is not relevant.

Comment: @Gimby : the form can be a JSP or a servlet form , the point is , I cant modify the source code of that JSP ,I too think it would not be allowed because of the Security issue , just not sure about it

I just wanted some java code to help me set the file in the form before the form is submitted

Comment: @Abhin : I have a running JSP on a server with a form in it , i need to set the value of the file input before the form is submitted

Comment: You seem to not understand the difference between client side and server side. Java runs on your server, the form is rendered and submitted on the client. You can't touch it with Java. You could touch it with javaSCRIPT, but then you are going to quickly discover the security restrictions.

Comment: @Gimby : I understand it , I just want to know if somebody knows a way out of it , many things are possible which I might not even be having any idea of it

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri'  Ok. I get your question now. First of all  `<input type="file">` opens a file browswer on the client. To add to that you have mentioned you do not want to 'browse' and select a file. I dont see the use of file input there. You are better off sending some path from the js to the server; if some path is what you want on the server.

Comment: @Abhin : if I send the path , it will not send the file along with the submitting form , i want to set the file field from the client machine so that when the form is submitted , image gets transferred on to server side